# What happened with polyfill.io 's CDN SSL certificate?

Tags: web-services, ssl, certificate

Certificate errors happen from time to time but this looks very fishy too me. A certificate for all those names? What's going on? Got the CDN hacked?

If so, what is the best thing to do? Removing it until it is fixed? That would be bad for a good part of our user-base. A hacked CDN is worse though, I guess… Maybe someone knows what really is going on?

[image]

Comment: I tried to retrieve the content with a browser that doesn't support HSTS yet (IE10 in this case) and the returned Javascript looks okay too me. Now I wonder even more what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "they" (see below) botched it, I can't see cdn.polyfill.io or *.polyfill.io on that large list, hence the error saying much the same.

(or maybe I overlooked some other problem)

To enlighten you about the names, virtual hosting (the act of hosting multiple websites on the same IP address on the same HTTP port) occurs over HTTPS /after/ the encryption is established, thus, at the time the server presents a certificate to the browser, it doesn't know which site exactly the user is after, that information is part of the encrypted request.

Thus, it is necessary for the certificate to cover all secure websites operating on that IP address and port combination.

CDN for Content Delivery Network, presumably a huge bunch of stuff is being hosted on this "network", probably not even owned by polyfill (i've no idea who they are), given the first name on the certificate is "f2.shared.global.fastly.net" you can speculate the true CDN, who actually messed up the cert, and what else they're hosting on the CDN there :)

Comment: In modern TLS (thus HTTPS) implementations there is a mechanism called Service Name Indication (SNI) by which the name you want to connect to is specified during TLS setup, as well as by the virtual host means in the HTTP layer.

So it's actually NOT necessary for secure sites to share certificates just because they're sharing an IP address _unless_ they want to work with pretty old software (Windows XP, Android 2.x) which does not implement SNI.

For the CDNs it works out easier to bundle lots of names into a certificate, and compatibility with Windows XP is a nice bonus.